# Return reference to local variable - C++

Tags: c++, variables, reference

## Question

How does one return a reference to local variable in a function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Array {
    public:
        bool stillAlive;

        inline Array() : stillAlive{true} {}
        inline Array(Array& array) : stillAlive{array.stillAlive} {}
        /* Other constructors... */

        inline ~Array() { this -> stillAlive = false; }

        // My attempt at returning a local reference
        // doesn't work because `tmp` gets destructed after the function returns.
        inline Array& clone() {
            Array tmp;
            Array& arrayClone = tmp;
            return arrayClone;
        }
};

int main(void) {
    Array array {};
    Array clone {array.clone()};

    ::printf("array: %s\n", array.stillAlive ? "true" : "false");
    ::printf("clone: %s\n", clone.stillAlive ? "true" : "false");
    ::printf("array.clone(): %s", array.clone().stillAlive ? "true" : "false");

    return 0;
}
```

I’ve seen the `static` keyword but I do not want the reference to be to the same variable always.

With pointers I know memory can be allocated on the heap so I’m pretty okay if the same has to be done with value variables (but I don't think that's possible).

---

> **EDIT**: Attempted a solution that could use self-contained pointers.

## Attempt

How about this then?
The local variable references a self-contained pointer which outlasts the scope of the function its called.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class Array {
    private:
        Array *cloneValue;

    public:
        bool stillAlive;

        Array() : cloneValue{NULL}, stillAlive{true} {}
        Array(Array& array) : cloneValue{NULL}, stillAlive{array.stillAlive} {}
        /* Other constructors... */

        ~Array() { delete this -> cloneValue; this -> stillAlive = false; }

        Array& clone() {
            delete this -> cloneValue;
            this -> cloneValue = new Array;

            Array& arrayClone = *(this -> cloneValue);
            return arrayClone;
        }
};

int main(void) {
    Array array {};
    Array clone {array.clone()};

    ::printf("array: %s\n", array.stillAlive ? "true" : "false");
    ::printf("clone: %s\n", clone.stillAlive ? "true" : "false");
    ::printf("array.clone(): %s", array.clone().stillAlive ? "true" : "false");

    return 0;
}
```

It seems to work as intended and there doesn't seem to be any memory leakage either.

Comment: It's impossible. The variable stops existing after the function ends. So, if you would return a reference to a local variable, what would such reference variable reference?

Comment: one doesn't.....

Comment: Consider using of `static std::unique_ptr<Array>` and reset pointer to a new instance of Array when it's needed.

Comment: You don't. Just return by value as the name `clone` implies.

Comment: But locally-scoped pointers can be allocated on the heap and returned from their function... Is there any way to apply this to non-pointers?

Comment: When you return a pointer, you return _a copy_ of the pointer value. "Reference" as a tool exists as a means of compile time checking that a pointer is always valid. You cannot return a reference to a locally-scoped pointer, too. You allocate the think the pointer points to on a heap.

Comment: Also note that all of your `inline` keyword uses are completely redundant, because functions defined inside the class definition are `inline` by default (and it probably does not have the meaning you think it does) and that accessing `.stillAlive` after the destructor has been called causes undefined behavior, making your program useless.

Comment: Just edited the question with an attempted solution...

Comment: @Lapys As everyone has been telling you your whole approach of having a `clone` function not return by-value is wrong. Why exactly do you insist on doing it differently?

Comment: `clone` doesn't do what expected. It always returns new Array. Just make `Array clone() { return Array(); }`.

Comment: @walnut: Just experimenting is all. It still seems off to me if I'm returning an explicit copy of `Array` via `Array clone(void);` but that doesn't seem to be the case under the hood.

Comment: Anyways, the second approach returns by reference and doesn't seem to cause any issues (Compiled with `-pedantic-errors` and `-Wall` flags).

Comment: @Lapys You are not returning a reference to a local variable, though. So now you are just doing something else and it is not practically safe, because as soon as someone saves the returned reference as reference (rather than copying it) and calls `clone` again, the program will have undefined behavior when the reference is used later.

Comment: @walnut: Oh... Ah, well. I guess the answer is **returning a reference of a local variable is impossible**

Comment: @walnut: What if an operator overload is used to prevent taking the address of the `Array` type?

Comment: @Lapys Its not about taking the address. It is about saving the reference. Change `Array clone {array.clone()};` to `Array& clone {array.clone()};` in your second code block and now you have a problem if you try to use `clone` after `array.clone().stillAlive` (undefined behavior). Also note that you cannot prevent taking the address. There is `std::addressof` which *always* gives you the address of an object, even if the address-of operator is overloaded/disabled.

Comment: There is no need for any function to return something.  Instead, pass a reference in the function parmeters.   Change from "int foo(int x, string y, float z)", change to "void foo(int x, string y, float z, int& returnVal)"

Comment: @2785528: Output parameters, eh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't do it**.

Return a copy of the local variable instead.

Because of the magic of C++11 move constructors, this will often be optimized away. I've even seen machine code which removed the move itself and operated as if the function had been passed a pointer to the object receiving the move.

With C++11 and later, it seems best to program as if copies are free. Then profile your code and if there really is a copy problem you can optimize it then.

Comment: Since C++17 most of the copy/move elisions are mandatory anyway. The only one that is not mandatory (but allowed) is the elision of `tmp` into the return value of `clone` (assuming it returns by-value). But OP's current code has a copy into `clone` in `main` anyway, which would be mandatory elided if `clone` returned by-value. So there is no benefit to OP's approach (even if lifetimes weren't an issue).